# Check if an image is transparent?

Tags: image-processing, metadata, exiftool

I use `exiftool` to check two images, but it doesn't say whether the image is transparent.

How can I check that then? Thanks.

Examples are [a PBM image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/pdf/p1-001-001.pbm) and [a PPM image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/pdf/p1-001-000.ppm)

```
$ exiftool test-001-001.pbm
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : test-001-001.pbm
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 121 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:02:17 11:01:03-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : PBM
MIME Type                       : image/x-portable-bitmap
Image Width                     : 900
Image Height                    : 1100
Image Size                      : 900x1100
```

```
$ exiftool test-001-000.ppm
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.60
File Name                       : test-001-000.ppm
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.8 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:02:17 11:01:03-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : PPM
MIME Type                       : image/x-portable-pixmap
Image Width                     : 900
Image Height                    : 1100
Max Val                         : 255
Image Size                      : 900x1100
```

Comment: What format(s) - PNG, GIF...

Answer (score 2):

I think it does, you need to look at this bit:

```
Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
```

That is for a PNG with transparency *available (just because it has a alpha channel  probably doesn't mean it is transparent - it could 100% opaque and have an alpha channel)* - for one without transparency:

```
Color Type                      : RGB
```

I have only looked at PNG formats exported from GIMP (which shows the layers as bold if non-transparent), not much else.

See also:

- [PNG Specifaction](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Alpha-channel)

Comment: doesn't have `Color Type` field in the output

Comment: Hmm... OK I'll have a look for something else :)

Comment: As PBM is a bitmap I am not even sure if it supports transparency... do you have an example image? (you can use Dropbox/Google drive/some online sharey thing link, as site like https://imgur.com will probably convert it). I can't get GIMP to export a transparent one anyway.

Comment: yes, updated.  why I want to check their transparency is because they are extracted from [a pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/pdf/p1.pdf), which `pdfimages` show has two parts: `image` and `mask`. I am not sure what `mask` means, but it sounds like transparent at least. Also see [my post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185320/674)